# Does sagemaker use nvidia-docker or docker runtime==nvidia by default or user need to manually set up?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nvidia-docker, amazon-sagemaker

As stated in the question, "Does sagemaker use nvidia-docker or docker runtime==nvidia by default or user need to manually set up?"

Some common error message showed as "CannotStartContainerError. Please ensure the model container for variant variant-name-1 starts correctly when invoked with 'docker run  serve’." and it didn't show as running with nividia driver.

So, do we need manually set up?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using tensorflow-gpu image as base images for my containers and I can use the gpu without specifying anything gpu related. When building docker containers for sagemaker you have to beware of folder structure and that your container is able to start with the command serve(which the error suggest).

If you have problem setting this up I find this [example](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/scikit_bring_your_own.ipynb) the most useful one to get the hang of it.